# Current date and time format

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to get a date and time displayed as '`12 Jul 2015, 18:24`'
(Current time in UK) on selection of a button called 'Log Incident'

```
[Log Incident]==1?new Date().toLocaleDateString():undefined
```

This is bringing back the following '`6:19:27 PM BST`'

How can I change it to the format I want '`12 Jul 2015, 18:24`'
All your help appreciated. I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: At least tell which programming language you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to write it in Javascript

Comment: Have you tried using a library like moment.js which can easily take care of all kinds of date formatting for you?

Comment: I tried moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); but it didn't return anything for me. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like momentjs:

```
moment().format('DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm'); // 02 Mar 2015, 02:01
moment().format('D MMM YYYY, H:m');    // 2 Mar 2015, 2:1
```

Otherwise, if you are masochist use just javascript:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'];
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth();
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var HH = today.getHours();
var min = today.getMinutes();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}

if (HH < 10) {
  HH = '0' + HH
}

if (min < 10) {
  min = '0' + min
}

document.write(dd + ' ' + months[mm] + ' ' + yyyy + ', ' + HH + ':' + min);
```

[Here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) are everything you need for display of date.
And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjBipVx3A3x1iMfQNBUO?p=preview) there's a PLNKR to try the library and difference pure JS/MomentJS.

Comment: Hi Marianoc, I tried moment().format('DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm');  but it doesn't work in the software I'm using any other old school methods?

Comment: "In the software youre using" -- what? html + javascript ... you downloaded momentjs? you tried the plunkr?

Comment: As @J-Dizzle said probably you haven't imported moment library. Anyway there's the solution to achieve what you want without any library but does it worth?

Comment: I'm a masochist :-) Is there anything I can use instead of document.write?

Comment: I didn't downvote you by the way. I'm very happy with your response

Comment: you can use jQuery, so `$('#htmlElementYouWantUpdate').html(dd + ' ' + months[mm] + ' ' + yyyy + ', ' + HH + ':' + min);` but a real masochist will use `document.write`.
PS: if you are happy with answer you could accept it ;)